# how to joint the left and right channel in mixing?

Tags: mixing

when i am arranging a music i want a good wide stereo image, so for example i use a pad that have a wide stereo image. but when i am mixing that music, i notice that my left and right channels are very different from each other, because of that pad i used. i can clearly see that on my izotope stereo imager.
so here is my question: can i still have the benefit of that pads wide stereo image but also have the same left and right channel?or is there any method for joint the left and right channel?

Comment: In simple terms, the wide stereo image is because of that difference between the channels, so you can't really have one without the other - but why do you want the left and right channels to be similar?

Comment: It also depends on how the pad is generating the wide stereo. If it's done by using different sounds in each channel, then panning them towards centre would simply narrow the field. if, however it was doing it by adjusting the phase of one side against the other, then narrowing the field would tend towards silence.

Comment: thanks both of you. i dont want to have similar channel , i just dont want to have this much differences  between channels. you know thats why i am confused right now. because its the differences that make stereo image. still i examine a lot of other mixers music,  they are greatly wide but almost have the same left and right channel. i can see it in izotope imager lissajous tab. also when i looking at polar sample tab, their polar samples are like a lot of dots but mines are combination of dots and irregular lines. hows that possible?

Comment: Don't worry about the meters or the imager, if it **sounds** how you want it to sound, then leave it that way. If it doesn't, then change it. Is there something about the **sound** that you don't like and you're not sure how to fix it?

Comment: yes. actually it is. when i listen my music on mobile devices or when i listen it in my car, i dont like it as much as i like it when i listen it on my monitor speakes.   i thought that maybe it is because of the differences between channels

Comment: Ah you're having what are called "*translation* problems", as in your mix doesn't translate to different listening environments. That's very common. That means you have to keep working on the mix to adjust the levels and EQ so that it sounds better in more places. It's not usually a stereo imaging problem.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - it probably took me 20 years to get rid of that issue; years of 'take the mix home, to the car, anywhere random'... I solved mine by eventually getting "the right monitors"\* for my workroom. \*Not necessarily the most expensive; I went from Genelec to dynaudio.

Comment: I'm voting to close/migrate this question as off-topic because it belongs on **_https://sound.stackexchange.com/_**

Comment: thanks . i know that i need alot more practice to reach that goal.  but from the moment i asked this question,  i analyzed more than 1000 wide pads. the result was intresting. some of this pads were huge but had alot differences between channels while the other pads didnt have this issue. maybe its because what tetsujin said before: how the pad is generating the wide stereo.

Comment: @Stinkfoot In no way does this fit Sound Design better than here. It's equally good (or not so good) in both places. The main problem I see with this question is that the asker needs to edit it to ask how to make mixes translate better, since that's the real issue as determined in the comments. As it stands, the question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a recording technique that might go a long way towards solving your issue. Explanation of the technique is probably to lengthy to explain here, but if interested, you may study up on it by researching "Mid-Side Stereophony". When applied correctly, it can create an aural center channel between your left and right side, with correct phase relationships between them, also allowing the combination of both channels into a monophonic mix should one be needed. Mixing can be less problematic if correct recording techniques are utilized initially.